# loading drbd module in centos 6.7

Tags: centos, high-availability, drbd

```
[root@NAS1 ~]# yum install -y kmod-drbd84 drbd84-utils
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

**--> Processing Conflict: drbd84-utils-8.9.5-1.el6.elrepo.x86_64 conflicts drbd-utils < 8.4**
```

while creating HA centos server, I installed new drbd although there was existing drbd.
After the conflict,  as depicted in below, I was not able to load the drbd module.

```
[root@NAS1 ~]# rpm -qa drbd
drbd-8.9.6-1.el6.monos.x86_64
[root@NAS1 ~]# service drbd start
Can not load the drbd module.
```

I 'm really new to structuring centos to HA form, so any advice related to using this module would be a great help.

Attached is are list of packages related to this

```
[root@NAS1 ~]# rpm -qa | grep drbd
drbd-bash-completion-8.9.6-1.el6.monos.x86_64
drbd-utils-8.9.6-1.el6.monos.x86_64
drbd-heartbeat-8.9.6-1.el6.monos.x86_64
drbd-xen-8.9.6-1.el6.monos.x86_64
drbd-udev-8.9.6-1.el6.monos.x86_64
drbd-8.9.6-1.el6.monos.x86_64
drbd-pacemaker-8.9.6-1.el6.monos.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have the kernel module installed; only the utils are listed above.

To install the kernel module from elrepo: `yum install kmod-drbd84`